# How to access varImp names from random forest in R

Tags: r, model

In R I can get the top 20 variables that are most important from `varImp(modelFit, scale=FALSE)`.

```
myVar = varImp(modelFit, scale=FALSE).
```

Then how can I access the variable names from `myVar`? Seems I have to manually type by looking on screen. Can I directly get them?

Answer (score 1):

`varImp` just returns a named vector. Where the name of the variable is the name for each element and the importance is the value

```
names(myVar)
```

should return the variable names. If you want the top 20

```
names(myVar[order(myVar, decreasing = TRUE)][1:20])
```